# Actionscript debug() method

Tags: debugging, actionscript, trace

I'm am trying to run a debug() method but I get the following error when I try to compile the code

```
Call to a possibly undefined method debug.                       debug("...");
```

I assume all I need to do is add an `import ...` where ... has the debug method defined. However I have tried looking for it and cannot find it.

I can't find what file to import. This is a large project that I got handed down to me to implement small features. I can add `debug("msg")` into some files with issue but others give me the error msg aboe.

I can't see `trace("...")` in the debug log.

Comment: What did you import to use `debug()`?  Also what about using `trace()`?

Comment: @Display Name - What is your code?

Comment: There is not ```debug``` function.

Comment: @helloflash my codee is debug("msg");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `debug` function this was obviously a custom function someone wrote. Nobody here can tell you where to find the file to import, you'll need to get more information from whoever you inherited the files from.

Another option is to just comment out the debug calls since based on the name they probably aren't doing anything but giving debugging information which most likely isn't required for the end goal of the program.